Why does echarts still render even the series encode value not match any dataset?
I am trying to use dataset option to render echart. But i found a weird case. Even my series encode value doesn't match any dimension of the dataset, the chart still renders, is this a bug or do i use it wrong?
Could anyone please help here? Thank you in advance.
Below is the option:
    option = {
    "dataset": [
        {
            "id": "chartData",
            dimensions: [
                    "12958",
                    "12958_1y",
                    "12958_2y",
                    "adb1eaef-fcd4-4c4e-a3e6-fe6974cf4be2",
                    "adb1eaef-fcd4-4c4e-a3e6-fe6974cf4be2_1y",
                    "adb1eaef-fcd4-4c4e-a3e6-fe6974cf4be2_2y"
            ],
            "source": [
                [
                    "2024-01-01",
                    "2023-01-02",
                    "2022-01-03",
                    341613,
                    265861,
                    346821.28571428574
                ],
                [
                    "2024-01-02",
                    "2023-01-03",
                    "2022-01-04",
                    354755.4285714286,
                    270617.71428571426,
                    350901
                ],
                [
                    "2024-01-03",
                    "2023-01-04",
                    "2022-01-05",
                    359314.71428571426,
                    272604,
                    353399.28571428574
                ],
            ]
        }
    ],
    "xAxis": {
        "type": "category",
        "axisTick": {
            "show": false
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "type": "value",
        "splitLine": {
            "show": true
        },
        "axisLine": {
            "show": false
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "appendTo": "body",
        "borderColor": "transparent",
        "show": true,
        "trigger": "axis",
        "enterable": true
    },
    "grid": {
        "left": "100px",
        "right": "20px",
        "bottom": "100px",
        "top": "40px"
    },
    "legend": {
        "show": true,
        "bottom": "0",
        "type": "scroll"
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "line",
            "name": "test series1",
            "showSymbol": false,
            "datasetId": "chartData",
            "encode": {
                "x": "testxnotfromdimension",
                "y": "testynotfromdimension"
            }
        },
    ]
}

And the result looks like below:


Echarts provides very compehensive default values. If you dont specify any data or dataset for the series, echarts uses the first dataset as data. And if you dont specify any dimension it uses the first two dimensions. It seems like it also falls back to the defaults on wrong inputs (like in your example).
You can observe it quite well if you change the order of dimensions in your dataset like I did here.

Thank you Matthia, So this default behavior looks more like a bug to me, if user has already set the dimensions, it should not fall back to the default case any more...
